# SQL Report Builder Replace Special Characters and Remove First and Last Character

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, report, builder

I'm using SQL Server Report Builder to create a report from a SharePoint list.

One of my fields is a multi-selection check box that saves multiple values. Issue is it is saving and outputting values like ";#Value1;#Value2;#Value3;#"

I was able to do "=Replace(Fields!fieldname.value,";#",",")" to have it output like ",Value1,Value2,Value3," which works, however, there is a comma at the beginning and end.

How do I replace the values and have it ignore the first comma and last comma on the output all in one expression?

Answer (score 0):

How about `=Join(Split(Fields!fieldname.value, ";#"), ",")`?

Comment: =Join(Split(Fields!fieldname.value, ";#"), ",") still has the commas before and after. The issue is SharePoint is adding a ;# before and after every value. The output comes out like ",Value1,Value2,Value3," ... need to remove the first and last comma now.